# Display data from Django database

Tags: django

I am trying to display data from mysql database. I have already uploaded data to database using django admin:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hws7x.png)

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Newsform(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='news_image', blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Newsform


def first(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html')


def show_content_from_database(request):
    headline_news=Newsform.objects.all()
    context = {
        'headline_news': headline_news
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ headline_news.headline }}</h1>
<img src="{{ headline_news.image }}">
</body>
</html>
```

I have blank page as a result. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headline_news` is a queryset, ie a list of all the Newsform items in the database. The queryset itself doesn't have a headline or an image, only the individual items in it do. So you need to iterate through it:

```
<body>
{% for headline in headline_news %}
  <h1>{{ headline.headline }}</h1>
  <img src="{{ headline.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Note also, as I show above, you need to explicitly use the `.url` attribute on an ImageField to get the value for the src.

Comment: i modified my .html with your code, but it is still blank page in browser. Did i miss something?

Comment: There's not enough information to help you further. What does View Source show in the browser?

Comment: View Source in my browser doesn't see  that part of code between {% for %} and {% endfor %}. Excuse me, can i chat with you somewhere in order to solve this?

Comment: That means that the template is not getting your objects. I think the problem is in your URLs: why do you have two views rendering index.html? Please show your urls.py and state which URL you are going to.

Comment: url from blog app: http://prntscr.com/l7l9tl . url from the project, that contains urls from apps: http://prntscr.com/l7lamk . Should i erase one view that renders index.html?

Comment: Don't link to pictures of text, show the text in your question. But your `show_content_from_database` view is not being called at all. Yes, remove the `first` method and change your "main/" URL to point to show_content_from_database.

Answer (score 0):

the attribut `url` search images uploaded inside `media` by default folder, and you can call it using `{{ headline.image.url }}`